# Execute conditional code onload()

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons on my page

```
<button id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" 
onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
&nbsp;
<button id="random" type="button" onclick="randomPeg();">Empty random 
peg</button>

function randomPeg()
{
window.location = window.location.href + "#refresh";
window.location.reload();
}
//At the start of JS code below
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
if(window.location.hash == "#refresh"){
    window.location.hash="";
    //Some more code
});
```

The first button just reloads the window.
On clicking the second button 'Empty random peg', I want to reload the page and then execute some more code after. I tried a few things with putting hash in the url but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It may be worth using ajax rather than reload

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Using the hash sounds a good idea for what you want to do.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: you can use cookies , local storage or GET parameters on the URL

Comment: @JeremyThille edited my post

Comment: `window.location = window.location.href + "#refresh"` already reloads the page, adding a hash. Don't add `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: It is still not working for me. It does not reload the page before //Some more code

Answer (score 2):

You could set a value into the persistent localStorage, and check at pageload if this value exists:

```
function reload(){
  localStorage.setItem("showfancystuff",true);
  window.location.reload();
}

//test on load
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("showfancystuff")){
    localStorage.removeItem("showfancystuff");
    alert("wohoo weve reloaded!");
  }
});
```

Comment: There is a problem in here. `if(localStorage.getItem("showfancystuff"))` is always true, because it is either the string `"true"` or the string `"false"`. You need to check against === "true"

Comment: Wouldn't this code run everytime on reload, where as I want it to run only during one button reload?

Comment: @user7623678 it will check on every reload, but wohoo will just show if it was reloaded usng the reload() function...